# Importing data from dbf to excel spreadsheet using Wing IDE

Tags: python, excel, dbf, wing-ide

I am trying to move a column of data (mean values) from a dbf file to an excel spreadsheet. I have been trying this with Wing IDE with no success so far. I am not a progamming student and this is a short term assignment. I am stuck on the part where I have to retrieve the file from the specific network drive and copy the data onto my local excel sheet. Help would be great. Thanks

Comment: Ya. dBase. The ending of the file is in dbf. The code I have so far is:  <br/>
  <br/>
import os, os.path, arcgisscripting  <br/>  
from dbfpy import dbf  <br/>  
filepath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname("E:/Yinsuo/MODIS/EVI.NDVI.STATS/"))  <br/>  
outfile = os.path.join(os.path.dirname("E:/Syed Workspace/Yinsuo.xlsx"))  

for IntFiles in os.listdir(filepath):  <br/>  
    if IntFiles.find("EVI.dbf") != -1:  <br/>  
        db = dbf.Dbf(filepath + "/" + IntFiles)  <br/>  
        print db  <br/>

Comment: You know you can just choose File->Open and select *.dbf for file types to simply open dBase files in Excel? No import or anything required.

Comment: I need to take data from hundreds of different dbf files and compile it into one excel worksheet. Doing this one at a time will take forever.

Answer (score 3):

You need the [Python Excel](http://www.python-excel.org/) tools, and I would also recommend my own [dbf package](http://python.org/pypi/dbf).

```
import dbf
import xlwt

dbf_files = ('file1.dbf','file2.dbf','file3.dbf')

output_xls = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet = output_xls.add_sheet('sheet_name')

for i, filename in enumerate(dbf_files):
    total = 0
    with dbf.Table(filename) as table:
        for record in table:
            total += record.some_count   # some_count being a field name in the dbf files
    sheet.write(i, 0, filename)
    sheet.write(i, 1, total)

output_xls.save('final.xls')
```

Hopefully this will give you an idea of how to handle your use-case.  Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I am having problems to use a field name in the dbf file in place of `some_count`. The dbf file comes from ArcGIS and every field name shown within ArcGIS is refused as `FieldMissingError: 'FID:  no such field in table'`. In this case FID is the ID of each row in my file.

Comment: @CF84:  field names are only accessible as lower case (so `fid` instead of `FID`.

Comment: Same error as above. How can I see what the fields are once the dbf file is read in?

Comment: @CF84: `print` the table, or `dbf.field_names(thing)` where `thing` is a table or a record.

Comment: Wait, this snippet does not convert from dbf to xls only, it sums the records of a field you specify. To just convert, I assume I need to get rid of the lines from `total` to `total+=...`, correct?

Comment: @CF84: It's not quite that easy.  If you ask a new question I'd be happy to answer it.  It's hard to put code in comments.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you can use ADODB with Python. You can run a query against a connection to insert into a Excel file from a DBF.

This works in VBA, hopefully you can translate.

```
strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" _
  & "Data Source=z:\docs\myexcel.xlsm;Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=No"";"

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cn.Open strCon

strsql = "SELECT * INTO [mynewsheet] " _
  & "FROM [dBASE III;DATABASE=z:\docs\].[mydbf.dbf] "
  cn.Execute strsql
```